# Debugging menu disabled in NetBeans 7.3

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have for long used NetBeans and Xdebug successfully to debug my PHP code running on a remote test server. However, after upgrading to NetBeans 7.3, the <kbd>Debug</kbd> menu is almost entirely disabled and I cannot set breakpoints anymore.

[image: NetBeans Debug menu disabled.]

What could be the cause of this problem?

#### Some extra info

- If I choose <kbd>Attach Debugger...</kbd> I can only select the Java Debugger (JPDA), which is not for PHP.
- If I choose <kbd>New Breakpoint...</kbd> I get a form suitable for Java programs, not PHP.
- My project settings in <kbd>Run Configuration</kbd> seem fine and
  unchanged.
- Settings in <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> ->
  <kbd>PHP</kbd> -> <kbd>Debugging</kbd> are Debugger Port: `9000` and
  Session ID: `netbeans-xdebug`.
- The remote test server's `phpinfo` page reports that Xdebug is installed: *This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
  Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
      with Xdebug v2.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans*

Comment: And you are sure you downloaded the PHP version of netbeans? If you go to file -> new project, do you see PHP in the categories on the left? I assume you are on windows?

Comment: @dbf: Yes, PHP is there. As far as I remember, I used the auto-update feature to upgrade. It does seem NetBeans has a problem identifying the application as a PHP project, but it runs fine and all files have the right PHP icon.

Comment: I guess you have multiple versions of Netbeans installed? If so, could you uninstall Netbeans 7.3. Then search the cache directory used by 7.3, you can find it from the [FAQ here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) and reinstall it without importing any profiles, this is normally something Netbeans asks when installing a newer version and detects you have previous versions. If all done right, check if everything works per default, maybe it's something in your profile settings that does something it should not. I have this problem occasionally on OSX (I'm a long time Netbeans user :).

Comment: I can only see one version on NetBeans on my computer, both in Windows' program list and on the HDD. But, I guess a reinstall of the program is worth a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a later version of NetBeans solved the problem. PHP Xdebug debugging now works the way it's supposed to. So to me this seems like a bug.

To be more precise, I installed NetBeans 7.3.1 and it now lives along NetBeans 7.3 on my HDD as it wasn't removed by the installation process. The installation asked whether I wanted to import settings from 7.3. Not sure whether this would corrupt the fresh install I clicked Yes.